# How to POST data to C# webservice from MQL4

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, mql4

I am trying to POST history data out of Metatrader with MQL4 to a web service written in C#. The problem I have is that the string in MQL4 is Unicode taking 2 bytes and the string in C# is ANSI. Therefore it looks like there is a space between every character on the receiving side.

```
#import  "Wininet.dll"
   int InternetOpenW(string, int, string, string, int);
   int InternetOpenUrl(int, string, string, int, int, int);
   int InternetCloseHandle(int); 
   int HttpOpenRequestW(int, string, string, string, string, string& AcceptTypes[], int, int);
   bool HttpSendRequestW(int, string, int, string, int);
   int InternetConnectW(int, string, int, string, string, int, int, int);
#import
#import "kernel32.dll"
   int GetLastError(void);
#import

void SendHistory()
{
   int i,hstTotal=HistoryTotal();
   for(i=0;i<hstTotal;i++)
   {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY)==true)
      {
         if(OrderSymbol()!="") // Skip balance statements for now
         {
            string body=GetBody();

            //--- Reset the last error code
            ResetLastError();
            // Only send newer Tickets
            if (OrderTicket() > lastOrderSent)
            {
               string headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
               string data = "";
               string acceptTypes[1] = {"application/json"};

               int HttpOpen = InternetOpenW(" ", 0, " ", "", 0);  
               int HttpConnect = InternetConnectW(HttpOpen, serverName, 27408, "", "", 3, 0, 0);
               int HttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(HttpConnect, "POST","/api/Transactions", "", "", acceptTypes, 0, 0);   
               bool result = HttpSendRequestW(HttpRequest, headers, StringLen(headers), body), StringLen(body));
               string lastError = kernel32::GetLastError();
               Print ("Last MSDN Error =: ", lastError);
               int read[1];
               Print("This is the POST result: ", result);
               InternetCloseHandle(HttpOpen);
               InternetCloseHandle(HttpRequest);            
            }          
         }
      }
   }
   return;
}
string GetBody()
{
   string bodyPart1=
     StringConcatenate("{","\"Order\"",":",OrderTicket(),",",
       "\"Time\"",":","\"",GetTimeString(OrderOpenTime()),"\"",",",
       "\"Type\"",":",OrderType(),",",
       "\"Lots\"",":",OrderLots(),",",
       "\"Symbol\"",":","\"",OrderSymbol(),"\"",",",
       "\"Price\"",":",OrderOpenPrice(),",",
       "\"StopLoss\"",":",OrderStopLoss(),",",
       "\"TakeProfit\"",":",OrderTakeProfit(),",",
       "\"CloseTime\"",":","\"",GetTimeString(OrderCloseTime()),"\"",","
       );
   string bodyPart2=
     StringConcatenate("\"ClosePrice\"",":",OrderClosePrice(),",",
       "\"Swap\"",":",OrderSwap(),",",
       "\"Profit\"",":",OrderProfit(),",",
       "\"Comment\"",":","\"",OrderComment(),"\"",",",
       "\"Commission\"",":",OrderCommission(),",",
       "\"Expiration\"",":","\"",OrderExpiration(),"\"",",",
       "\"MagicNumber\"",":",OrderMagicNumber(),",",
       "\"AccountNumber\"",":","\"",AccountNumber(),"\"",",",
       "\"Id\"",":","\"",OrderTicket(),"\"","}"
       );
   return(StringConcatenate(bodyPart1,bodyPart2));
}
```

on the C# side it looks like this:

```
// POST: api/Transactions
[ResponseType(typeof(Transaction))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTransaction(Transaction transaction)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Transactions.Add(transaction);
    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (TransactionExists(transaction.Id))
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = transaction.Id }, transaction);
}
```

The Transaction class is

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Lots { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal StopLoss { get; set; }
    public decimal TakeProfit { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CloseTime { get; set; }
    public decimal ClosePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Swap { get; set; }
    public decimal Profit { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public decimal Commission { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
    public int MagicNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

But because of the Unicode vs ANSI difference in string handling, the Transaction object received by the Web Api controller is always empty.
I tried to use StringToCharArray to convert the Unicode string to ANSI, but the HttpSendRequestW expects a string as a body argument. The Internet*A functions of Wininet.dll will not even reach the Web Api endpoint because the URL is Unicode as well and instead of http://localhost it tries to call http://l.

I could not use WebRequest because of it's limitation to port 80 and 443. My port (at least for testing) is 27408.

Can anyone help we to get this working?

Comment: Did you try to use `WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:27408//api/Transactions")` (notice the :27408 ) and that didn't work for you? C# is Unicode aware. It is unclear why you think C# only accepts ASCII. If the `transaction` is empty it is more likely the payload in the body didn't match what the binder expected. Can you try with PostMan or any other tool to verify what payload works?

Comment: MQL has WebRequest() function for GET and POST. data is sent as a char array so you can try without wininet.dll

Comment: With WebRequest, I am getting the Error 5200 when using the port 27408. See https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/65854. The documentation states clearly:  _Server port is automatically selected on the basis of the specified protocol - 80 for "http://" and 443 for "https://"._